# GPG (PGP) decryption speed issue

Tags: cryptography, pgp, rsa, gnupg, .net

We are new to using GPG and we have a very strange issue with decryption speed when using RSA keypairs, which are generated by using different tools (GPG for Windows, DidiSoft OpenPGP Library for .NET and SecureBlackbox).

So we have 3 RSA public/private key pairs that have the same properties (hash/compression algo, ciphers) and key size of 2048 bits and we got the following results:

100 decryption operations for each private/public keys:

1. RSA keys generated by GPG for Windows:

   DidiSoft: 90 ms/1 decryption
   SecureBlackbox: ~420 ms/1 decryption
2. RSA keys generated by DidiSoft lib:

   DidiSoft: 38 ms/1 decryption
   SecureBlackbox: 40 ms/1 decryption
3. RSA keys generated by SecureBlackbox lib:

   DidiSoft: 39 ms/1 decryption
   SecureBlackbox: 39 ms/1 decryption

All the tests are using the same C# code with just the file name changed to switch public/private keys. Why is there so big difference in the execution time and what might be the cause?

Passphrase: qwerty

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2

mQENBFYP1skBCAC3CoaV+MiROdkvH6Ilcq/eXXV8ckteyp+urhKqCyyPRuKVcdb9
nIuC79b7xqrfx+SNWFiD2WVPtoD2NelPHe15mQjImKyYhBN9z79PiijtXHHB6hH6
Z6wkXyWUzLXAsySUKdFQc2lr+7vcVD/Oc4rUUuIYqpyTlZxiLlT3h73ta9S1wwJn
Q+6iPPd88Mc7cEUysghGmFDLmAIXSjwTxPSG234QDKyNFK4X8fP7BQ2Yp9v3yG81
zWeKFG0fOQgVa4ReWjq/OwC+WoirDFuwY610nrxjEO5HwSaniHEjSRcTbSGN8AmS
dOv9mjakQ1a0U/wFIUBOT9/DRQVgI8T56UW5ABEBAAG0KWdwZ3dpbmRvd3N0ZXN0
IDxncGd3aW5kb3dzdGVzdEBlbWFpbC5jb20+iQE5BBMBAgAjBQJWD9bJAhsDBwsJ
CAcDAgEGFQgCCQoLBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQT+WOTX/34l3ZzAf+LsiTeFHxdHDj
p+rokuitS6HL98gVAiLwx7wj901MGbvOJL6aUtt1KGffpqZuRisPB6ATK5qT+YUU
I2uu5az6ISDxLYbKGpoiWdLPK+39R6KOgGJ45OmgKLNKX/biHzzJplaoK75pQBmK
0+bBZPabQOO9xY7Xi9OZONYvjrnpeX6haIZrg1j6wnj9M13M/D/BmCGMm3UJAKhw
rHYLjDlc0gOUY8kDBqqIz5uczEJp6iyc6RmUgKLgS0fIOGMf0vFwznxV43DMoUWL
kmZkpm0RfvgfU0dv/VLmAlUtwXGIQy626jiTo0F6oKdfxpUwZzZ7jCId9ViyAtiM
DKDqfSEl37kBDQRWD9bJAQgAoUnwPIU/Js8u4PsFr0BBd1tTDU5u+MdtHbFCeUJV
iHtaOe01/PEgZFehKtPU2oDwAlaRs71AaK8NK6hTrqP11wO3eOYXzt2n0195q1Ud
3LYQCCi6jnIXkJ3PO+Ur8P0gE5jAjAqnf/C3V42sbV8XvZIFdCsDO/xvqW1tDSUJ
Fg7qQz4YQKhFTjYNM9ME0l5DGz/+i8lCeKy7fWjV0oUuKkAu2e/V6g4c//sf3n+o
UFvLHn+N5SMxAkol3US7F0qi8I6Z+PU6EkApLIblogI2lJ7AY1gGE+hXR9USzqJS
dBaQFA94xP7T1j7rOBsJn8n+WiDtTZ1H1Lwt7uEG9tR30QARAQABiQEfBBgBAgAJ
BQJWD9bJAhsMAAoJEE/ljk1/9+JdaEoIAIzSTLV0Bk9D8gI1YqO62g8Cajyr1JjJ
IsZk9A1KHn7fHK9YpnoT3ivL1ktB4xaAN64jEbxTWuhVUnZ92JJ+mw+0i0zRjUf0
BGtGOIPizBerYKBS5rlYXe/eWNHkIr0Qt2uwxSNp0x9MF0bYTSOS+SlSsVwEHUKI
t4FJq61zdvZdgzCmXXNkUymSjJkFgDl3znzlLzIcG2vQP8T6pdy99SxxcKPnCOZq
wn/h5jKOLemYsoyN+5tuok0KaTUa1juKnzbASXGrDOuQCXM05h5mQ0rsw8GVWKbC
l1cncYyDfXHHrXo1KrN4w0V2UGD9TK+Lo5XXDKrNg18jqRt+P9OQoYw=
=Ofoe
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2

lQO+BFYP1skBCAC3CoaV+MiROdkvH6Ilcq/eXXV8ckteyp+urhKqCyyPRuKVcdb9
nIuC79b7xqrfx+SNWFiD2WVPtoD2NelPHe15mQjImKyYhBN9z79PiijtXHHB6hH6
Z6wkXyWUzLXAsySUKdFQc2lr+7vcVD/Oc4rUUuIYqpyTlZxiLlT3h73ta9S1wwJn
Q+6iPPd88Mc7cEUysghGmFDLmAIXSjwTxPSG234QDKyNFK4X8fP7BQ2Yp9v3yG81
zWeKFG0fOQgVa4ReWjq/OwC+WoirDFuwY610nrxjEO5HwSaniHEjSRcTbSGN8AmS
dOv9mjakQ1a0U/wFIUBOT9/DRQVgI8T56UW5ABEBAAH+AwMCeugZ5cGb/hnHv7KW
vJiuyWitARpF5YQt1qdLeUA1ilHGCrnwz/nDEBtbjm6u8/w+r40US/rvW7/m6Fuz
AQcbtU13OSEwqQcjl406SBML2L68u8JK06YdUaHm5HCUBf6HFbEdrlt+khLqZhGk
Pj0axtCnOLIT+tVk/C0DrX2R+cmATEpzhc8h31jg4CqBSagr2qIvvmw8Sca9fh/8
0u8oHcWck1kaqJ8zymwLPmLwR2mSOKZhFtYyQr3lwQNURw4eBGvp0h4Ba6pvtekt
9HHKC/KCe7kSNhX+9rRPA1zBBYki2GrvI97Up0drLya1i2+yHS7W8tiI8xxBmyXY
ij7fIfrjwYQOO6VAv5+Bxn6pY3//uzLuYv6aRBs/InN5m2ltw1rD0xSaMAIyJCcd
T754PLte/NduOPL1EdoiQbULUWubSx090UlfZz5yn6NdRmByq8zw5Q0/4l38erwg
OV3fdHHw8n3b0oFONXg+nyMgrL73pXqgnE5RGdgGtZJ8tqRqiGMCQ1/XxnlQhdMy
tJXbvAMFTsSYnb/3iMWIOozw+uY1+xCJ7wppwpdd7cy5J5Ijng0UF3VLkhuOyjum
o49+LRSKYo9/PiVpjA2FNrGwzmmX3zMpiklqRCdIxcGzvzGBwO2+sg4Kg5uUuJBI
coGZEx2XxIZnPzmkBYFJCXjerSccK1cuC/Y7HkbmmbdIDKr57q2jWQX42dTUkYR4
1aLI5eLTP2SfeIcONxOTctCZIDMBDzjKSDFIq3AOJS5mL7ikmKVlkR3yf2+HEvIX
FwlAPBDweV6EsJ5mFt+5nyFU+ONABivll6+md8Ko83D4jUD+mqBmL4KFHf6u+Ge5
bYlh5F0Y0880GlqT9HlNIM6/4okz0pUtW6V/6WFlpEJX3iv5lX6CrxusjWb0MpZV
RLQpZ3Bnd2luZG93c3Rlc3QgPGdwZ3dpbmRvd3N0ZXN0QGVtYWlsLmNvbT6JATkE
EwECACMFAlYP1skCGwMHCwkIBwMCAQYVCAIJCgsEFgIDAQIeAQIXgAAKCRBP5Y5N
f/fiXdnMB/4uyJN4UfF0cOOn6uiS6K1Locv3yBUCIvDHvCP3TUwZu84kvppS23Uo
Z9+mpm5GKw8HoBMrmpP5hRQja67lrPohIPEthsoamiJZ0s8r7f1Hoo6AYnjk6aAo
s0pf9uIfPMmmVqgrvmlAGYrT5sFk9ptA473FjteL05k41i+Ouel5fqFohmuDWPrC
eP0zXcz8P8GYIYybdQkAqHCsdguMOVzSA5RjyQMGqojPm5zMQmnqLJzpGZSAouBL
R8g4Yx/S8XDOfFXjcMyhRYuSZmSmbRF++B9TR2/9UuYCVS3BcYhDLrbqOJOjQXqg
p1/GlTBnNnuMIh31WLIC2IwMoOp9ISXfnQO+BFYP1skBCAChSfA8hT8mzy7g+wWv
QEF3W1MNTm74x20dsUJ5QlWIe1o57TX88SBkV6Eq09TagPACVpGzvUBorw0rqFOu
o/XXA7d45hfO3afTX3mrVR3cthAIKLqOcheQnc875Svw/SATmMCMCqd/8LdXjaxt
Xxe9kgV0KwM7/G+pbW0NJQkWDupDPhhAqEVONg0z0wTSXkMbP/6LyUJ4rLt9aNXS
hS4qQC7Z79XqDhz/+x/ef6hQW8sef43lIzECSiXdRLsXSqLwjpn49ToSQCkshuWi
AjaUnsBjWAYT6FdH1RLOolJ0FpAUD3jE/tPWPus4Gwmfyf5aIO1NnUfUvC3u4Qb2
1HfRABEBAAH+AwMCeugZ5cGb/hnHHwZjlQmuJaRqwYw3sfipiQptXjyQ9omPBo7t
yEqo/a/FtvRBTxlo2Dc+BpXBNuLmq3i7jSugrsVkVZ5lmz/R6wGFP1Mjc13VzFDV
psQXE3Zuaxjy0umfSaSb3AD0XVAmD2WIb/sP+DhyS5Cfx6sPrl9mXKsFtezplytt
ZVlUQImKeTDZy2MUkK/qGkXUCqM/lmW4pJsPVdE9ZicZoib9mub7LNh+n/9+p+Tq
Y/pe8XJ0K4PD5QI7EaM4uUDDnxBGNoU7wcnWpcu0LmPKLn7+muuxfkhE9xTgeHyW
I4OIhtaUjWgtm/qbHme4v4qB9AeBY1N8Aklmqmhxbd2epqmj3bA+/QH92kTatub2
v3sWAV8WVL40U9hLzbcnuXxa0/S8NRotcTRCSD7TZhxIlL+WqTxn6NsFdbqabUGX
hlDClJv02H7BPWbQTVP4+yxY4W+fVPFiajs5fAbA/9o5B5Re0MJZU1FXmKuMXInL
FCFu/dAPghkOs7ShYEKQu1EDVNmgQbI56jaCKnS/oyS/iYjMKHxgZUt/svGah91p
UFh07npfqYpIqcnQCmuiGqS5xbTbDB7LauOeXxWJV2x9Xgljk4YOXg6XLS94d7Jl
EYLurBgdKWE2kyCuCS8bpMfOCSV3s4NGckdO2XWWBAlv/t6Fm531Lz3COBZEa0a0
Wyc9DL1Ha4gJI0Sffbklnsw10OiJEPVHz8WT3bW55mLaS8TxlyVV3h85IhkRnrXD
zGqgsJOS1lzw19myDLIvTt6TTZ5AhB/2LPGzo8rOFh5K7eEPQf0EQBT0o45CEHU7
5Yz0Qz2xq8J0GmKIo5ZYGmGL0IF4Pq0FpTTI00RMzYpXPyHWkcX51hLMoE1w44qM
TT2SbrZiXhMaP1a7hc0RW6Rvn1+7wTlbb4kBHwQYAQIACQUCVg/WyQIbDAAKCRBP
5Y5Nf/fiXWhKCACM0ky1dAZPQ/ICNWKjutoPAmo8q9SYySLGZPQNSh5+3xyvWKZ6
E94ry9ZLQeMWgDeuIxG8U1roVVJ2fdiSfpsPtItM0Y1H9ARrRjiD4swXq2CgUua5
WF3v3ljR5CK9ELdrsMUjadMfTBdG2E0jkvkpUrFcBB1CiLeBSautc3b2XYMwpl1z
ZFMpkoyZBYA5d8585S8yHBtr0D/E+qXcvfUscXCj5wjmasJ/4eYyji3pmLKMjfub
bqJNCmk1GtY7ip82wElxqwzrkAlzNOYeZkNK7MPBlVimwpdXJ3GMg31xx616NSqz
eMNFdlBg/Uyvi6OV1wyqzYNfI6kbfj/TkKGM
=1WOu
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: What was the data you tried to decrypt ? Was it constant or random ? Did you try generating other pairs of keys ?

Comment: For getting an idea what's going on, would you be fine with posting the private keys and an encrypted message for each of those? It seems you generated testing keys anyway.

Comment: @FrancoisRenaud-Philippon the data was random 2048 bytes. Yes I tried different pairs of keys

Comment: @FrancoisRenaud-Philippon I generated 100 random arrays of bytes, encrypted them and then tried decrypting the data by using those two C# libs and each pair of keys

Comment: It looks like the key pair generated by GPG for windows is giving you issues. I'd try regenerating the keys via GPG for windows and seeing if the issue persists, it may just be that you hit an edge case somewhere with that particular key pair.

Comment: I already tried a few key pairs but can see the same results

Comment: I suggest you contact Eldos support and ask them directly. In my experience, they are quite responsive.

Comment: Could you post a sample PGP private key generated by GPG?

Comment: Sure. I will update the question

Answer (score 4):

For those who are not familiar with OpenPGP, I have to first clarify that the RSA key (and algorithm) has a limited time performance impact over decryption speed, because the OpenPGP archive format looks like this:

*session key-RSA encrypted || data encrypted with a symmetric algorithm (e.g. AES) by the session key*

So, basically the speed depends (especially over large amounts of data) on which symmetric algorithm was used for encrypting the input data. Interesting part of OpenPGP is that the keys may contain symmetric algorithm preferences inside, and the encryption process may take them into account when the data was packed.

Having in mind the above paragraph, the data encrypted with the GPG RSA key may have been encrypted with different symmetric algorithm, than the key from DidiSoft [OpenPGP Library for .NET](https://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/) and Eldos. In order to test keys equally, you will have to specify explicitly the symmetric encryption algorithm, or make sure that all keys have only one and the same preferred symmetric cipher key preference.

Comment: By the way, the key pair from your post has AES-256 as the default symmetric cipher.